# Unable to select requested UK visa duration on the online application form

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, long-term

This is related to the question regarding UK long term standard visitor visa. It was asked [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/120930/long-term-standard-visitor-visa-to-the-uk) before but the answer pointed to in the comment does not address the question. I want to know where in the form do I get the option of selecting the duration of my UK visa (6 months/2/5/10 years) which was available in the [old form](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/101409/requirements-for-long-term-uk-standard-visitor-visa-2-5-10-years) it looks like.

In the new form, the payment page only gives me the standard 6 month fee option. [image: new form]

Has anyone faced this issue or found a solution.

Comment: Do additional options show up when you select one of the payment methods?

Comment: No, it just asks for the appointment date and card details after that.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved. For those looking for the same:
[This link](https://www.visa4uk.fco.gov.uk/home/welcome) definitely shows the 2,5, 10 year options in the beginning itself.
I had a tough time getting the visa duration option in [this link](https://visas-immigration.service.gov.uk/product/uk-visit-visa).