# UK Long Term Standard Visa no longer an option?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, long-term

Apparently we can no longer apply for a long term visitor visa? The .gov site channels you automatically to the 6  month visa. I've tried going through the older Visa4UK site as well, and it doesn't give the option either. What gives?
[This](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/129480/uk-long-term-standard-visitor-visa) question perfectly describes the problem I'm having, only the answer no longer works.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's still an option for people over 18 years old. This from Gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa (Link below):

"If you need to visit the UK regularly over a longer period, you can apply for a long-term Standard Visitor visa that lasts 2, 5 or 10 years. You can stay for a maximum of 6 months on each visit.

If you’re under 18 years old when you apply, your long-term Standard Visitor visa will only be valid for up to 6 months after you turn 18.

Fees
A Standard Visitor visa costs £95.

The fee for a long-term Standard Visitor visa depends on its length:

2 years - £361
5 years - £655
10 years - £822 "
https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa

Comment: Umm.. 6 months after the applicant turns 18. If he is 10 at the time of the application, the maximum validity for yhe visa will be until he is 18 1/2.

Comment: Yeah, that's what they SAY. But once you actually apply, nowhere does it give you the option to apply for a longer term visa. Frustrating, but I guess I don't have a choice. Six month visa it is. :(

Comment: Strange, but enjoy your six months anyway!