# Length of visit for 2 year UK tourist visa

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, standard-visitor-visas, repeat-visits, long-term

I am planning to apply for long term tourist visa for my mom and I wanted to know how long can she stay in UK if granted a 2 or 5 year visa. And if it's 6 months, then can she come back by making an international visit for few weeks?

Comment: What ties to her country of residence does your mother have if she can contemplate 6 month-long / repeated visits to the UK? She is probably unlikely to get a long-term visitor visa unless she has previously held several short-term visas

Comment: She has been here once on 6 month visa, she holds indian passport and she is my husband’s only parent.

Comment: In that case, this is worth reading https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/101409/requirements-for-long-term-uk-standard-visitor-visa-2-5-10-years/101413#101413

Answer (score 2):

The holder of a long-term UK visitor visa can stay for up to 6 months on each visit. Having a long-term visa doesn’t remove the need to demonstrate that the holder is a genuine visitor as stated in the Immigration Rules V 4.2 https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules
(a) will leave the UK at the end of their visit; and
(b) will not live in the UK for extended periods through frequent or successive visits, or make the UK their main home

Making visa runs will quickly lead to your mother being refused entry if Border officials think she is trying to use a visitor visa to effectively live in the UK. There is no stated period in the Rules, but as a general guide your mother should spend at least the same amount of time outside the UK as in it.

Comment: There are probably also tax consequences of spending more time in the UK than outside it.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I don't think there is. You only pay tax on UK earnings no matter where you are in the world

Comment: @BritishSam If you're resident in the UK, you owe UK tax on your income, unless you've already paid tax on it somewhere else and there's an appropriate taxation agreement between the countries concerned.

Comment: @DavidRicherby you will never be classed as a resident on a tourist visa, unlike the USA if you stay more than 6 months in a year.

Comment: @BritishSam No, "You’re automatically resident if [...] you spent 183 or more days in the UK in the tax year" [UK Government](https://www.gov.uk/tax-foreign-income/residence).

Comment: Same word, different meaning: resident for tax vs resident

Comment: @DavidRicherby Thanks didn't know that! I'm guessing this would be very difficult to do on a tourist visa, as an IO probably wouldn't allow you to spend more than that in the UK normally