# I really in depth help ( UK tourist Visal refused Twice ),and makes so uneasy

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals

I was denied UK visa based on the followings:

1. You have stated that you will visit the UK for 6 days.
2. I note that you were refused a visa for this purpose on 23 March,2019. At that time the Entry clearance officer had not been satisfied that you had sufficiently demonstrated your studies in resident country(Asia). You have not addressed this , nor have provided any evidence that you are currently pursuing a course of study there. I note that you have you have temporary residence in the (Country in Asia). The documents you submit do not demonstrate your long term intention on completion of any studies.

**Note : I have been to UK on 6 months tourist visa,even Schengen country and Singapore( didnt over stayed nor abuse the visa stipulations ). I applied for 2 years tourist visa,and submitted back documents from my University ,showing am a bona fide full time PhD Student,with  8 months resident visa of my current resident country to show.**

2. You have submitted a bank statement  in your name for the (Bank Name). I note that there are several cash deposit over the reporting period. The source of these fund is not clear and they dont reflect your stated annual income of 12,200GPS.

***Note: I provided the name of sponsor(mom) with her payment payments slips,and other back others documents from my local bank to support the source of it.***

3. I consider that you have not shown sufficiently strong family ,social or economics ties outside the UK or reason to return to your home country at the end of the trip.

***Note: I secured my first UK tourist visa(6 months) with two landed properties in my city, resubmit additional landed property with stock shares (3 landed properties of mine ) ,and a letter from my parents stating am the sole heir of their  3 residential properties in the heart of my city. I dont have kids nor married***

Comment: If you need in-depth help then you need an immigration lawyer, not a bunch of strangers on the internet.

Comment: @Unknown How many times have you visited the UK and how long did you stay in the UK on your last visa? What was your premise for applying for a long-term Visitor visa?  https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/101409/requirements-for-long-term-uk-standard-visitor-visa-2-5-10-years/101413#101413 Where are you living now and when does your current resident visa expire? It seems that you were able to demonstrate strong enough ties to your home country for your first visa, but your circumstances are currently different and your ties to your country of residence are not sufficiently compelling

Comment: See also [UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/92121/11491).