# Is there any way to avoid having to leave passport at embassies on visa applications?

Tags: visas, passports, applications, passport-stamps

My citizenship does not allow me visa-free entry to most of the countries. Due to the nature of my work, I have to travel to various places quite frequently, and often require visitor/business visa. Right now it is quite a huge obstacle for me that some countries (e.g. the US and UK) require me to leave my passport at the embassy when I apply for a new visa or extension, which often takes around a week just to get my visa stamped and my passport mailed back to me. This prevents me from traveling (and doing my work) for at least a week. I am wondering if there are any ways to avoid having to leave the passport in the embassy, or travel without a passport?

I see that one option is to get a second passport, however even that is not enough in extreme cases (e.g. right now I have to extend my US visa and apply for UK visa, and need to make a flight to Europe at the same time). I believe my country does not allow to issue a third and more passports.

I wonder if there are any ways to negotiate/pay for priority services (AFAIK it's not an option even with priority processing for the UK) with embassies/visa centers so that I can keep my passport during the processing and come in person to get visas stamped without delays?

Comment: Unfortunately I think this question is too broad, since it is going to be different for different countries. For the UK, it is [available at some application centres](https://www.vfsglobal.com/en/individuals/article-uk-visa-guide.html). If it isn't available at the one you use, then it's tough luck unfortunately. You can also consider applying for longer term visas.

Comment: @MJeffryes, the "Keep Your Passport" thing does not really solve the issue, from what I understand you still have to submit your passport _after_ your visa is approved and wait for some days just to get your visa stamped.

Comment: Well yes, of course at some point they have to stamp your passport. I can't see anyway around that.

Comment: @MJeffryes, right, but e.g. it takes a Swiss embassy ~3 hours to stamp a visa onsite, but for UK or US it takes at least around a week and sending passports by post.

Comment: Embassies take as long as they take, there's nothing that can be done to speed up the process. Even ambassadors can have this problem. Frequent travellers tend to get around this by having multiple passports. (I mean, multiple passports from the same country, I am not talking multiple citizenship). Whether that is permitted in your case is hard to say since you don't say which country issued your passport. Many countries do not admit that they allow multiple simultaneous passports until you demonstrate a clear need, so don't dismiss the idea even if semi-official sources say it isn't allowed.

Comment: @efremale If you've successfully applied for a few UK visas before, you should consider applying for a 2, 5 or possibly even 10 year visit visa. There's [an answer here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/101409/requirements-for-long-term-uk-standard-visitor-visa-2-5-10-years) explaining the circumstances under which these are granted.