# Family of settled person/citizen visa for UK (above age 18)

Tags: standard-visitor-visas, uk-citizens, family, uk-residents

Hope y'all doing great?
I have a couple of questions

1. I got a 6-month visit visa in November (Expires May). I am using 2 months on my first visit which ends in January and will be back home shortly.

I would like to come back to the UK in April-June (Another 2 months) for basically the same purpose I got the 6months visit visa for (to visit family), would also like to attend events relating to my business industry/personal growth as well. (Remember my 6months visa would have expired by May so I have to renew to be able to travel April-June)

Is it advisable to apply for a 2-year visa or should I stick to renewal for 6 months?? (Remember I only used 2 months from my 6 months and never overstayed).

Secondly, does anyone know about the category called ''FAMILY OF A SETTLED PERSON VISA''?
My parents are UK citizens but I am not and I am above age 18, is there any type of visa that allows me to join them long term that is not a visit visa?
I have been seeing stuff about it online but the UK GOV website is a bit ambiguous about people over 18 so I wanted to ask if anyone knows about or has experienced it and how they went about it.

I await your response. Thanks

Comment: We don't try to answer questions like 'Do I stand a good chance...'. We have no idea. Your visa application is decided on many things, nine of which we have access to. Your second question about joining your parents long term should be asked on [expatriates.se]. I would start by confirming that you don't already qualify for British citizenship. With 2 British parents it's possible that you do.

Comment: Thanks @Arthur'sPass . I have edited and rephrased the question now. I hope that is better. I know I do not qualify for citizenship. Was just wondering if the ''Family of a settled person visa was viable for someone above age 18. I know it is for under 18s definitely. I wil check the expatriates link. Thank you so much

Comment: Unfortunately, unless you are *financially dependent* on your parents (eg, you're a student, and you depend on money from your parents to live) you will not qualify for a family visa. But Arthur's Pass is right. In what circumstances did your parents become citizens?

Comment: oh I see. I am not financially dependent on them. My step dad was a citizen then he got married to my mom decades ago and she became a citizen through the marriage route. So I guess I have to keep apply for a visit visa then? Thanks @MJeffryes

Comment: Yes, in that case, there is likely no route other than a visit visa for you to come to the UK.

Comment: Q2 should be asked on Expatriates. Does this answer your question about a longer-term visa? Requirements for long-term UK Standard Visitor Visa (2, 5, 10 years)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/101409/requirements-for-long-term-uk-standard-visitor-visa-2-5-10-years)

Comment: yes, it does. thank you @Traveller