# Why the change in visa type from Visa to Entry Clearance and the reduced validity from 2 years to 6 months

Tags: visas, uk

In 2018 I applied for UK standard visitors Visa and was successfully issued 2-year with Visa  which has the resemblance of the schengen Visa. In 2021 I applied for another 2-year visa and instead I got Entry Clearance Visa and for only 6 months. Why the change in visa type and the reduced validity time. Can I get refunded for the difference in visa fees of 2 years (GBP390) to 6 months visa (GBP 95).

Comment: What reason did you give for needing a longer-term visit visa? Are your personal circumstances the same as they were when your 2 year validity visa was issued in 2018? You won’t get a refund of the fee difference if UKVI has decided that you do not qualify for a 2 year visa https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa Did UKVI provide any explanation? Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/101409/requirements-for-long-term-uk-standard-visitor-visa-2-5-10-years

Comment: Fees are just that, fees - they cover the application, not the outcome.  You cant claim a fee refund for a refusal for example - the application was considered, and the outcome is what you ended up with.

Comment: Two of my previous visas were for 2 years. My son studies in London since 2016.

Comment: @MSS When is your son due to finish his studies in the UK? The expiry date of your visa may well be linked to that, since your reason for frequent visits ends when his circumstances change

Comment: A visa _is_ a form of entry clearance.  The fact that the words on the two visa stickers are different is not particularly important.  The difference in the design is most likely due only to the UK's departure from the EU.

Comment: HIS BRP expires in September 2023. Why if I paid for a 5-year visa and then I get 6 months, isn't that a ripoff. Processing an application should cost the same regardless if it was for 2-year or 5-year or 10-year visas.