# Need clarification on applying for UK Visitor Visa from a Red list country

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, covid-19

The GOV.UK visitor visa [advice](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/coronavirus-covid-19-advice-for-uk-visa-applicants-and-temporary-uk-residents) for applicants from Red list country states that:

> If you’re applying for a visitor visa
> Your application decision may be delayed if you’re applying from a red list country where travel to the UK is suspended. You’ll receive your visit visa when suspension of travel is lifted if your application is successful.

I am little confused by this. Does this mean my application would be evaluated when the travel restrictions are over *OR* I can apply now and a decision would be made i.e. **visa granted/refusal** but I would not know about the outcome until travel restrictions are over.

Please clarify this to me.

Comment: When is your intended travel date? You can’t apply more than 3 months in advance of that date, irrespective of red  list changes

Comment: @Traveller yes I am aware of the 3 month rule. I am planning to travel from Aug 25 to Sep 20.

Comment: Regardless of the bureaucratic machinations of the visa application process, is there any practical difference for you as a traveler between your two options?  However I get the feeling that you really want to know about a potential *rejection* as soon as possible.

Comment: @Peter M, my main concern is on the travel dates, if they decide to evaluate the application after restrictions are eased and if that date is after my planned travel date then it may cause issues.

Comment: So your concern is that your date of travel will end up being before the visa being issued.  I have 2 problems with that.  1) In general you have no idea that the visa will even be issued and 2) you are trying to guess when the travel suspension will be lifted.  Without positive confirmation of both of those points I wouldn't even be attempting to make travel plans

Comment: @Peter M, if I do apply when restrictions are easy, it takes 1-2 months to apply and receive a visa decision. Due to various variants, the restrictions can be put back again. My last visa got expired in similar way and I couldn't travel at all.

Comment: Well either you wait until things have totally settled down, or you roll the dice and take a gamble.    Even if you know when the visa will be processed/granted, you don't know if the restrictions will be re-applied - making the entire visa process moot.

Comment: Could pandemic be used as a reason to apply for a 2 year visitor visa to allow flexibility. I would anyway be making 1/2 trips to UK per year to meet my gf.

Comment: You could try for a longer validity period, but you’d likely need a history of visiting the UK to stand a chance of getting it https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/101409/requirements-for-long-term-uk-standard-visitor-visa-2-5-10-years/101413#101413

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of my friend recently applied for a visitor visa and this is what the UKVI responded in e-mail.

[image]