# Applying for UK visas 2 years as a First timer

Tags: visas, uk, nigerian-citizens

Can I apply for UK Visas 2 years as a first-timer? How possible is this? I am From Nigeria. I have travel history from East Africa and West Africa

I have Travel history for Rwanda, Kenya, Benin Rep.

Comment: You can certainly apply, and if UKVI issues a visa it will have the duration UKVI thinks is appropriate given their evaluation of you and the purpose of your travel(s). Whether you'll succeed will depend on specifics about your travel history (where, when, how long) and personal information (you, your circumstances, and your family circumstances), and showing ties to Nigeria that'd suggest you'd return after being in the UK. We are a bunch of amateurs interested in travel. No one here knows any of those matters, nor do we know what UKVI will do. The only way to know for sure...is to apply.

Comment: Do you have a credible reason to demonstrate why you need a longer-validity visa? Does this answer your question? [Requirements for long-term UK Standard Visitor Visa (2, 5, 10 years)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/101409/requirements-for-long-term-uk-standard-visitor-visa-2-5-10-years)