# Can a husband/wife apply for UK Visas with different validities?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, b1-b2-visas, tourist-visas

I have been issued a UK standard visitor six-month validity visa 3 times in 2014, 2017, 2018 whereas I have traveled only twice in 2014 and 2017.

Now I’m married and I have two infant children who have never been issued a UK visa. What are the possibilities of all of us applying for a 5-year visa? If not, is it okay to separately apply for a 5-year visa for myself and 6-month each for my dependents?

The purpose of visit is tourism only.

Comment: Are you referring to a standard visitor visa? B1/B2 is a USA visa class, not a UK one.

Comment: @brhans yes sorry. Corrected that

Comment: There’s nothing to prevent you from applying for either option. You’ll need to justify requesting a longer term visa in any event. If you’re asking ‘what are my chances’ this https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/101409/requirements-for-long-term-uk-standard-visitor-visa-2-5-10-years might help