# For UK Visitor Visa, what evidence to provide for source of funds?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds, long-term

I am currently planning to make an application for UK long term visitor visa in next few months for my mother.

I and working full time in UK and will be sponsoring my mother for her visa application and will provide my UK account bank statement and will be confirming sponsorship.

I plan to provide my 6 months bank statement of my UK account with sufficient funds. Additionally, my mother has her own long term Fixed Deposit (for more than last 6 months) with enough funds in her home country as well.

For the first 4 months, my mother had enough savings to manage her monthly expenses, and I didn't transfer funds to her savings account (linked to the above mentioned Fixed Deposit) and her balance in the savings account dropped. However, after adding her Fixed Deposit, her total savings was be sufficient for her visit.

To support her living expenses, thereafter, last month there was a small cash deposit and thereafter I transferred small amounts twice from my account in my mother's home country to her savings account.

Thereafter, to support her living expenses further, I transferred another small amount next month from my UK bank account to her savings account using via transfer.

The respective two bank transactions in her account in the previous month (from my account in my mother's home country) displays my name (as the individual who transferred funds) only, but not my account number.

Additionally, I have requested a letter from the bank for sender verification of these two transactions in the last month.

I have the following questions:

1. Do I need to provide evidence for the cash deposit? If yes, what evidence should I provide?
   Should my mother/myself/both of us provide declaration letter(s) confirming receiving/sending these funds respectively.
2. For the 2 transactions which I made to transfer funds to my mothers account last month (from my account in my mother's home country), from source of evidence perspective, do I need to provide some evidence? If yes, what evidence should I provide?
   Can my mother/myself/both of us provide declaration letter(s) confirming receiving/sending these funds respectively.
   Alternatively, should I provide my bank statement as well for source of funds verification/tracing.
3. Can I transfer some more small funds next month? (I am thinking to leave it as currently my mother's doesn't need more funds, as it would have been with the 28 days period from the date of submission of passport).
4. Should I provide 3 months or 6 months bank statement, considering I didn't had to support her during first 4 months as the funds were sufficient for her monthly living expenses?
5. Does my above support to my mother indicate I have added funds for her visa application?
6. If I show relationship between me and my mother will it be sufficient to justify the financial support provided?

Any help/advice will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Just to be sure, you have understood that a 10-year visitor visa does not give her the right to stay in the UK for 10 years, right? It only gives her the right to visit multiple times over a 10 year period, six months at a time max, and she should spend more time outside the UK than inside, and not try to live in the UK through successive or repeated visits. How long is she planning to stay on her first visit? Has she come to the UK previously? When? How often, how long? Any other stays in countries like US/Canada/Schengen? Does she have any revenue of her own? Any reason to go back home?

Comment: Also the 10-year visa is really expensive and can cause you to lose a _lot_ of money should it be rejected. I would probably start with a standard 6-month visa at first.

Comment: 1. Provide evidence / explanation of who/where the £250 in cash actually came from. 2. Provide your foreign bank statement and whatever Western Union issues as transaction confirmations. A ‘declaration’ from you/your mother is completely useless IMHO. 3. You can transfer whatever is your *normal* support for your mother; if you send more explain why. 4. Provide 6 months’ statements. Are you a British citizen or have ILR? Your mother won’t get a visa for longer than your own immigration status AFAIK

Comment: 2 year to 10 year is a big jump https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/101409/requirements-for-long-term-uk-standard-visitor-visa-2-5-10-years Spending nearly 12 months in UK plus 5.5 months in US out of around a 2 year period kind of undermines a claim to having a compelling reason to return to her country of residence

Comment: @user137980 Are the FD funds readily accessible to your mother? AFAIK she will have to provide her savings account statements so that the ECO can tie up the transactions between you. The visa length you apply for depends on your risk appetite, personally I’d go for either another 2 year or a 5 year visa but then I’m pretty risk averse.

Comment: AFAIK transferring unexpected funds to an account to support a visa application can be a red flag.

Comment: @user13790 Stack Exchange websites (including this one) do not provide for, and actively disfavor, personal off-site discussions between participants. Because of the multiple comments here, one of the moderators may move comments to [Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=travel.stackexchange.com). You or Traveller (or anyone else), can request such a move using the "Flag" button below the text of your question.

Comment: DavidRecallsMonica, thank you for kindly advising. As I am new to this website, so I was not aware of the rules and regulations of this website.

Comment: You're welcome. You can review the [Help](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help) pages for more information.

Answer (score 4):

You’re raising quite a few questions but in essence the answers all boil down to the same principles:

- applicant and financial sponsor should provide six months’ worth of statements so that the ECO can understand the applicant’s financial situation, including any transactions between you and your mother
- provide evidence of the source of *all* income/credits in *all* of the statements submitted

Declaration letter(s) from you/your mother confirming sending/receiving cash are worthless IMHO - they won’t prove where the cash originated from, which is what the ECO will be interested in. Personally I don’t see a huge problem in transferring £100 to your mother in September - it’s not a large amount and appears in line with the support you give her.

See [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) for more insight into the topic.

On the subject of which long-term visa to apply for (mentioned in a comment), only you can decide. There is some advice here [Requirements for long-term UK Standard Visitor Visa (2, 5, 10 years)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/101409/requirements-for-long-term-uk-standard-visitor-visa-2-5-10-years)